# Model State is valid and success message displaying but no data being added to the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6

I have an application that accepts user data and then adds it to the database. If data is successfully added, it displays a success message. However, when I test it, I get the success message but no data is being added to the database.

I initially created the views using Entity Framework. Originally the model did not contain the `IsCovered` field. I added that later and updated the model from the database. After I did that, it stopped adding data to the database.

Here is my controller:

```
// POST: Shifts/Create
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create([Bind(Include = "ShiftID,Date,StartTime,EndTime,StoreNum,Id,IsCovered")] Shift shift)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            shift.Id = User.Identity.GetUserId();
            shift.StoreNum = User.StoreNum();
            db.SaveChanges();
            TempData["Success"] = "Shift posted for " + shift.Date.ToString("mm/dd/yyyy") + " at store #" + shift.StoreNum + " successfully.";
            return RedirectToAction("Create", "Shifts");
        }

        return View(shift);
    }
```

Here is my model:

```
    public partial class Shift
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Shift()
    {
        this.CoveredShifts = new HashSet<CoveredShift>();
    }

    public int ShiftID { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:MM/dd/yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode =true)]
    public System.DateTime Date { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name="Start Time")]
    public System.DateTime StartTime { get; set; }
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:HH:mm tt}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [DataType(DataType.Time)]
    [Display(Name ="End Time")]
    public System.DateTime EndTime { get; set; }
    [Display(Name ="Store Number")]
    public string StoreNum { get; set; }
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public bool IsCovered { get; set; }

    public virtual AspNetUser AspNetUser { get; set; }
    public virtual Store Store { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<CoveredShift> CoveredShifts { get; set; }
}
```

And here is my view:

```
@model SSM_V5.Models.Shift
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Post a Shift";
}
@using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/themes    /smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.1/jquery.timepicker.min.css" type="text/css" />
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        $('.datepicker').datepicker({
            showOptions: { speed: 'fast' },
            changeMonth: true,
            changeYear: true,
            dateFormat: 'MM/dd/yy',
            gotoCurrent: true
        });
        $('.timepicker').timepicker();
    });   
</script>
</head>
<h2>Post a Shift</h2>


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    @if (TempData["Success"] != null)
    {
        <p class="alert alert-success" id="successMessage">@TempData["Success"]</p>
    }
    <h4>Please add your shift details below.</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
    @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.StoreNum)
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Date, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control datepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Date, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10" >
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control timepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EndTime, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EndTime, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control timepicker" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EndTime, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-8">
            <input type="submit" value="Post Shift" class="btn btn-success" />
        </div>
        </div>
        </div>
```

Any insight into this problem is appreciated, as well as general feedback about my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you are not adding anything to the database in your controller.

You are simply just saving changes.. of which in this case means nothing because you are not adding anything to the database.

You are missing this line:

```
db.Shifts.Add(shift); // missing line
db.SaveChanges();
```

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: Wow... can't believe I overlooked that! Thanks for your help!

Comment: No problem!  You, along with myself (and I'm sure others) have overlooked things like this many of times!  Just mark this answer as accepted so that this question can be seen as answered!  Happy coding!